# semisimplicity for subgroup

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

let $G$ be a group (can assume finite) acting on a vector space $V$, and assume that the action is semisimple. Let $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Why also the action of $H$ on $V$ is semisimple too?

Comment: Is there any condition on the characteristic of the field? because Maschke's theorem shows that any $F[G]$ module is semisimple when $|G| \in F^{\times}$

Comment: actually not. The problem is that these group arise as galois group acting on Tate modules of an abelian variety.

Comment: You should write in this format (with @) in order for the person to whom you're replying to receive a notification about your comment. (Of course since you're unregistered, *my* formatting won't make a difference :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [Clifford's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_theory).  Roughly:

> **Theorem.** Take a simple G-submodule W of V.  Then W is a direct sum of simple H-submodules U1⊕…⊕Un.

Let U be any simple H-submodule of W.  Then the G-conjugates of U are also H-submodules, since H is normal.  They intersect as proper H-submodules of U, and so intersect trivially.  They span W since their span is a G-submodule of W.  Since every H-submodule of V is a direct sum of simple G-submodules (G acts semisimply), and each simple G-submodule is a direct sum of simple H-submodules (as we just showed), V is a direct sum of simple H-submodules, and so is semi-simple.

Comment: In your first two sentences, you are assuming that simple $G$-modules are semisimple when restricted to $H$, no?

Comment: The first sentence names the theorem.  The first two sentences after "Roughly" state the theorem.  The rest indicates why it is true.